# Azure Cache (Preview) OutputCache - High CPU - Slow

Tags: azure

I have an MVC 4 (Razor) website and I've enabled Azure Cache (Preview) (Co-Located) for both the session and the outputCache providers.  Since I enabled it, each web request causes a massive CPU spike and results in 3-5 second page response times while debugging.

I have narrowed the problem down to the outputCache provider.  If I disable it in the web.config, the site runs great.  No CPU spikes.  I am not using page output caching yet... so no reads/writes should be occurring.  The session provider runs fine via Azure Cache (Preview).  Below is my outputCache config.  If I disable it, the site runs without CPU spikes.  Any thoughts?

```
<caching>
  <outputCache defaultProvider="DistributedCache">
    <providers>
      <add name="DistributedCache" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheOutputCacheProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="default" dataCacheClientName="default" />
    </providers>
  </outputCache>
</caching>
```

Comment: I'm evaluating Azure Cache too, even if I just considered the Dedicated role option.
As you are debugging it I assume you are running the solution locally on the Development Fabric, correct? Do you run multiple instaces of the web role and configured high availability (Backup Copies = 1) between the instances?

Comment: Are you using the cache for anything else? I'd be curious to see the `dataCacheClients` configuration from your Web.Config file as well as the Cache Settings on the "Caching" tab of the WebRole properties page.

Comment: I've formatted my machine, installed VS 2012 and reinstalled the Azure SDK, redownloaded my NuGet packages and the problem persists.  Anytime I turn on the outputCache provider massive CPU spikes for each web request.

Comment: As requested, here's the dataCacheClients section:  <section name="dataCacheClients" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientsSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />

Comment: @DavideB I am running a co-located Role with 30% cache size between web servers.  The problem is when debugging locally on the dev fabric.

Comment: @Chris Koenig I am using the cache for both Session and any/all caching (output or basic ASP.NET caching).  Session is very small (4 keys right now...)

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior on a single extra small web-deployed instance. Adding the azure outputcache to web.config slows down every request, considerably. No MVC actions are using OutputCacheAttribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the issue is due to the Web Optimization Framework.  It does not have server caching enabled for non-default cache providers (e.g. Azure Cache Preview).  So each time a request is made, the web server has to rebundle which is causing the CPU spikes.  A future version of Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization should enable server caching again.

Here's the [issue](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/46) on on CodePlex.

Comment: thanks for your comment bill. it doesnt look as if they have released this fix yet. did you come up with an alternative fix?

Comment: The issue seems to be closed on CodePlex