# MVC 4 on Azure - @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, bundling-and-minification

---

I'm using

> Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.0-alpha1 (updated from 1.0.0 - also not working)

in my project. I realize that my script section render very long (whole page rendering is very long). I placed some time logger and ... it is very strange, only

> @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

take over ~2 sec! (it contains reference to 2 files, without * char). Section with JQ, JQ UI and JQ Validate render over ~4 sec. Other scripts (my custom scripts) render < 0,1 sec. Where can be a problem? Azure ? Cache on Azure? Someone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a non standard output cache on Azure?  There is currently a bug which results in very slow performance as caching becomes disabled.  This is a question discussing that issue, which you might be running into: [Azure Cache (Preview) OutputCache - High CPU - Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230246/azure-cache-preview-outputcache-high-cpu-slow)

Comment: Thanks. That's the problem... I'm using caching 'Co-located Role'.